# AngularJS - Initialize form data based on value

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, angularjs-ng-init

I am trying to add edit functionality to my app. In one view, I have a button that brings you to the edit page.

```
<button ng-click="editMission(selectedMission.key)">Edit Mission</button>
```

The value `selectedMission.key` is used to determine what to initialize the edit page's form data with.

In the controller the function looks like this:

```
  $scope.editMission = function(key){
    $location.path('/edit');
  }
```

On the edit page I have:

```
<div data-ng-init="editInit()">
```

And in my controller I have:

```
      $scope.editInit = function(){
        var query = myDataRef.orderByKey();
        query.on("child_added", function(missionSnapshot){
          if (missionSnapshot.key()==key){
           ...
          }
        });    
      }
```

How can I run the initialize function based on the key value from `editMission`. Should I use some getter/setter approach with a global key variable? I tried just placing the `editInit` code in `editMission` but the form data does not populate on view load.

Comment: Can't you set scope variables with *editMission()* and then bind those variables to the form in the view (ng-model)?

Comment: Are you using `ngRoute` or `ui-route`?

Comment: @drakyoko It is possible to do that, but the fields and radio buttons do not visually change to the variable values.

Comment: @georgeawg I haven't used either, not sure what they are.

Comment: I recomend you use [AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire).AngularFire is the officially supported AngularJS binding for Firebase. It is integrated with the AngularJS `$q` service.

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common practice is to use a service to share variables between views/controllers.

So in your case you would use the getter/setter approach as you suspected. I don't know what exactly you're trying to do, but the service in your case would look something like this:

```
app.factory('missionKeyService', function() {

    var currentMission= {};            

    return {

        setMissionKey: function(missionKey) {
            currentMission.key = missionKey;
        },

        getMissionKey: function() {
            return currentMission.key;
        }
    }
})
```

And in your controller1:

```
//include 'missionKeyService' in your controller function params 
$scope.editMission = function(key) {
    missionKeyService.setMissionKey(key);
    $location.path('/edit');
}
```

And controller2:

```
//include 'missionKeyService' in your controller function params
$scope.editInit = function() {
       var currentKey = missionKeyService.getMissionKey();
       //do something with this key
       ...
}
```

Comment: You are just missing one closed curly bracket to close the return

Comment: Sorry yeah, was coding on here on the fly. Edited my answer. Also removed the extra bracket bits in `controller2` (doesn't apply to he `editInit ` function).